# Running PBC in Windows - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cryptography

I have managed to find correct headers for [PBC](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/) in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 on Windows 8.1 (I just modified the existing for Linux).

However, when I try to compile a little piece of code using these headers, I get the following errors:

```
1>PBC_sig.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__gmpz_clear@4

1>PBC_sig.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__gmpz_init@4

1>PBC_sig.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @element_to_bytes_x_only@8

1>PBC_sig.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @element_from_bytes_x_only@8
```

Note that I want to statically link with PBC.lib (generated from Linux code in the above 
website with the help of MinGW and MSYS windows compilers).

From the above errors it is clear to me that something is wrong with the static linking procedure, but I do not understand what I can do to fix them. (I have put the headers inside VS's own folder and PBC.lib inside VS's own folder.) If you do not already know, PBC uses [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), from which the above first two errors derive. Furthermore, when compiling PBC in MinGW, I used the static-compiled version of GMP (compiled before with MinGW).

So, my question is: how to fix the above errors?

Comment: Did you also link with gmp.a (or .lib, depending on what mingw gcc creates), and did you build both with the same version of gcc? Also make sure everything is 32bot or 64bit but no mix? *I have put the headers inside VS's own folder and PBC.lib inside VS's own folder.* don't do that, it's a maintainance nightmare. Learn how to use the compiler/linker options properly instead.

Comment: @stijn I did link with gmp.lib, building them with the same g++ compiler and everything is 32-bit. About headers, I created one folder inside VS and put everything there, so it's easy to find. About the library it is only one file (pbc.lib), so it easy to find too.

Comment: Can you show the code? I downloaded a pcb.lib and gmp.lib found on the net, added a bunch of code including element_to_bytes_x_only and it links properly. The problem seems to be be the linker looks for decorated names, while the should be plain C. E.g. with verbose linking the first line here is `Searching D:\Temp\pbc-0.5.14\pbc.lib: Found ___gmpz_clear` but in your case it looks for `@__gmpz_clear@4`. The headers do contain `extern "C"`, right?

Comment: @stijn The code.cpp is [here](http://expirebox.com/download/f320b9f61dd604858c6a1ae81fd51c70.html) and headers and libs I am using [here](http://expirebox.com/download/bb11b21368b0e904db929a2f98975add.html). In the last file you can see the exact directory I am putting them. If you can, I would ask that you check my libpbc.lib file (remember it is from MinGW). And something else about the headers: in order to compile correctly the headers, I deleted from pbc_utils.h two (or three) __attribute__ modifiers (as they are GCC-specific and I am using VS2013). I forgot to mention I am using C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here are the final details on "how to install PBC and use it on Windows":

1. Download PBC (htxp://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/download.html) and [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) SOURCE CODE **ONLY**, **NOT** COMPILED BINARIES.
2. Download and install the latest MinGW (with MSYS) (htxp://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) (preferably in C:\MinGW).
3. Unpack GMP in %GMP_Dir% and PBC in %PBC_Dir%.
4. Copy MinGW directories inside MSYS directory (which means: copy all subfolders of C:\MinGW (EXCEPT C:\MinGW\MSYS, of course) into C:\MinGW\MSYS\1.0).
5. Run `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat` and inside it, type `cd %GMP_Dir%`.
6. Type `configure` (I advise you to firstly run `configure --help`, in order to customize your build and especially you **NEED** to tweak these options: `--prefix=%GMP_InstallDir%`, `ABI=32` (or 64 or ... depending on system type), and `--host=CPU-OS-VENDOR`. For instance, I built it with `ABI=32` and `--host=i386-pc-mingw32`, so as to support x86 CPUs (tip: you can use `config.guess` in order to see your system type, mine was: i686-pc-mingw32). IN EVERY CASE READ `configure --help` **VERY CAREFULLY** and for tweaking CPU support read **[this](https://gmplib.org/manual/Build-Options.html)**).
7. After the above finishes, type "make", then "make check" (**ALWAYS DO THIS**) and finally "make install".
8. Now copy from *%GMP_InstallDir%* all directories to "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\".
9. Inside the aforementioned command prompt, type `cd %PBC_Dir%`.
10. Do as above steps 6 and 7 indicate, **WITH THE EXACT CPU TWEAKS** you used for GMP compilation and (of course) changing *%GMP_InstallDir%* directory to *%PBC_InstallDir%*.
11. Close command prompt.

Now, back to Visual Studio:

1. Create a **C** (I suggest C, as I have read C++ is having some issues with the assembly-optimized code of GMP) project for your desired binary (executable, (dynamic or static) library, etc.).
2. Apply the following transformation to **pbc_utils.h** file (located in *%PBC_InstallDir%\Include*)

FROM

```
/*@manual log
Reports error message and exits with code 128.
*/
void pbc_die(const char *err, ...)
    __attribute__((__noreturn__))
    __attribute__((format (printf, 1, 2)));

/*@manual log
Reports informational message.
*/
void pbc_info(const char *err, ...)
    __attribute__((format (printf, 1, 2)));

/*@manual log
Reports warning message.
*/
void pbc_warn(const char *err, ...)
    __attribute__((format (printf, 1, 2)));

/*@manual log
Reports error message.
*/
void pbc_error(const char *err, ...)
    __attribute__((format (printf, 1, 2)));
```

TO

```
/*@manual log
Reports error message and exits with code 128.
*/
#ifdef _MSC_VER

__declspec(noreturn) void pbc_die(const char *err, ...);

#else

void pbc_die(const char *err, ...)
__attribute__((__noreturn__))
__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

#endif

/*@manual log
Reports informational message.
*/
#ifdef _MSC_VER

void pbc_info(const char *err, ...);

#else

void pbc_info(const char *err, ...)
__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

#endif

/*@manual log
Reports warning message.
*/
#ifdef _MSC_VER

void pbc_warn(const char *err, ...);

#else

void pbc_warn(const char *err, ...)
__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

#endif

/*@manual log
Reports error message.
*/
#ifdef _MSC_VER

void pbc_error(const char *err, ...);

#else

void pbc_error(const char *err, ...)
__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));

#endif
```

(the reason is that the `__attribute__` is GCC-specific, thus inexistent in VS.)

1. Apply the following transformation to **pbc_curve.h**:

FROM

```
#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)
// Internal:

element_ptr curve_x_coord(element_t e);
element_ptr curve_y_coord(element_t e);
element_ptr curve_a_coeff(element_t e);
element_ptr curve_b_coeff(element_t e);
element_ptr curve_field_a_coeff(field_t f);
element_ptr curve_field_b_coeff(field_t f);

void curve_from_x(element_ptr e, element_t x);
void curve_set_si(element_t R, long int x, long int y);
void curve_set_gen_no_cofac(element_ptr a);

#pragma GCC visibility pop
```

TO

```
// Internal:

element_ptr curve_x_coord(element_t e);
element_ptr curve_y_coord(element_t e);
element_ptr curve_a_coeff(element_t e);
element_ptr curve_b_coeff(element_t e);
element_ptr curve_field_a_coeff(field_t f);
element_ptr curve_field_b_coeff(field_t f);

void curve_from_x(element_ptr e, element_t x);
void curve_set_si(element_t R, long int x, long int y);
void curve_set_gen_no_cofac(element_ptr a);
```

(the reason is that the `#pragma GCC` directive DOES NOT exist in VS.)

1. Write your code, with statements such as `#include <pbc.h>` in the beginning.
2. In menu Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties do the following (2 steps):

   a. In C/C++ -> General in "Additional Include Directories" type:

   `%GMP_InstallDir%\Include;%PBC_InstallDir%\Include\pbc;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

   b. In Linker -> Input in "Additional Dependencies" type:

   `C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\libgcc.a;C:\MinGW\lib\libmingwex.a;%PBC_InstallDir%\lib\libpbc.a;%GMP_InstallDir%\lib\libgmp.a;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

Now you are ready to compile (don't forget to Click "OK" and not close the properties window). However, you should be informed that it will have some warnings about "locally defined symbol *(something)* imported from function ...". Do not worry, unless it causes an error to your app.

I have checked these warnings and they are due to the different versions of *msvcrt* (.dll, .lib, .a, etc.) MinGW and VS use. This indicates no problem AND **DO NOT LINK WITH LIBRARY "C:\MinGW\lib\libmsvcrt.a"** to fix it, as you will have the following error if you do so: "multiple .drectve sections found ...".

**WARNING**: DO **NOT** forget to replace ALL of the *%(something)%* (such as *%PBC_Dir%*) with DIFFERENT directories, so that you will be easily able to maintain (recompile, etc.) binaries when a new release comes out. **ALWAYS** use the LATEST ONLY release of GMP and PBC, as some SEVERE errors are periodically fixed.

NOTE: I was forced to change two links above (the ones inside parentheses) to htxp, as I don't have reputation needed to post more than 2 links...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly is wrong, but here is a solution that works for me and requires no compilation with MingW:

- download [pbc binary distribution](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/files), I used pbc-0.5.14-win32-bin.zip
- download [pbc source distribution](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/files), I used pbc-0.5.14.tar.gz
- download [gmp binary distribution](http://progressive-living.info/opensource/gmp), I used gmp-4.2.2_win_lib_h.zip
- unpack pbc binary to e.g. c:/libs/pbc/lib, (so all files like pbc.lib in that dir)
- unpack inlude dir from pbc source to e.g. c:/libs/pbc/include, (so all files like pbc.hin that dir)
- as you did already, remove the `__attribute__` stuff from pbc_utils.h (*)
- unpack gmp to e.g. c:/libs/gmp (so that dir contains include, info and lib)
- create a new empty C++ project in VS2013
- set Configuration->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories to `c:/libs/pbc/include;c:/libs/gmp/include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`
- set Configuration->Linker-Input to `c:/libs/pbc/lib/pbc.lib`
- add code, use `#include <pbc.h>`, build

(*) if it works out, I suggest you give this back to the community and submit a proper patch for pbc_utils.h with some `#ifdef _MSC_VER` lines where msvc has no equivalent attribute (msvc does have the equivalent for noreturn)

Comment: Well, that's not what I said my target was. Although it really compiles fine, let's look [here](http://expirebox.com/download/68064f3aa48e23e14b80674632ea6acb.html). IT SAYS it uses pbc.dll, while I said "_Note that I want to statically link ..._". So, how to port this into a static version?

Comment: Also, not to forget "patched" [pbc_utils.h](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=13288391583455975880).

Comment: Not sure why static link is a hard requirement for you, the benefits, if any, are small, but I can't figure out how to build static libs for gmp/pbc so cannot answer that question.

Comment: Anyway I found how to statically compile the code, and fixed some errors (I will post a full answer after I resolve the below error, so that no-one else trying to use PBC on Windows will get "stuck"). So, the only bug left to be ready is that of "undefined reference to _snprintf" MS VC compiler emits. I managed to correct a similar issue "undefined reference to _chkstk_ms" by including C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\libgcc.a to the libraries, but I cannot spot anything on the Internet saying in which library (I hereby mean **MinGW** lib) "_snprintf" is located. Can you help me out with that?

Comment: I have it in libmingwex.a - find this using `ar t` for example `ar t libmingwex.a` and grep through it

Comment: Just now that I started using BLS signatures, I found out that I always get the following warning: "warning: could not open /dev/urandom, using deterministic random number generator" which according to [PBC manual](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch06s01.html) shouldn't be happening on Windows, as there PBC uses CryptGenRandom(). So, I believe that my --host=i386-pc-mingw32 option is wrong, I tried --host=i386-pc-winnt but NOTHING corrects this warning... Do you think I should post a new question for this or do you know something that could help me?

Comment: Best to post a new question for that, or else file a bug report for PBC: after all if the claim is it builds/runs on windows, they should have clear build instructions