# PBC on Windows: CryptGenRandom()

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, cryptography, cryptoapi

I have been using PBC on Windows after a lot of effort with MinGW and now I noticed that (I have started using BLS signatures) I always get the following warning when running a statically MinGW-compiled version of PBC:

"*warning: could not open /dev/urandom, using deterministic random number generator*"

which according to [PBC manual](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/manual/ch06s01.html) shouldn't be happening on Windows, as there PBC claims to use CryptGenRandom(). So, I believe that the *--host=i386-pc-mingw32* option I used is wrong, however I tried *--host=i386-pc-winnt*, but with no success.

Finally, I have to make an observation: when examining the final "problematic" .exe using ExeInfoPE I saw **NO** imports from advapi32.dll which is where CryptGenRandom() lies, whereas the MinGW-compiled DLL in PBC website actually **HAS** such imports.

Therefore, I believe I have to use some special command to PBC when "./configure"-ing it, so as to guide it to compile the file "arith\init_random.win32.c" instead of "arith\init_random.c" (you can find these in PBC source). So, my question is: how can I correct the above warning? (which, according to the above PBC manual, means that no random output from PBC functions should be cryptographically used)

Note: You can see my compilation options in my answer in [Running PBC in Windows - Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446726/running-pbc-in-windows-visual-studio) and download PBC binaries and source from [here](http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/download.html).

Comment: I browsed their git history (`http://repo.or.cz/r/pbc.git`), particularly, changesets related to building *.win32.c files, and it seems to me that this support was present only in CMakeLists.txt (removed in commit 76edbd6e5283f89f32b06a3f7356898c05c4340d) and Makefile.mingw (removed in commit b0a500b6961cb13a15af04f1f857cb2df4932e27). So I think your best bet now is to just replace *.c with *.win32.c files before building.

Comment: Don't interpret me wrong, your question is entirely on-topic and welcome here. But you may get better results on the PBC mailing list for these kind of questions - their will be a very limited amount of people that understand about PBC here (and no, I don't know PBC either).

Comment: PBC mailing list wasn't answering to me EVEN for the (solved in StackOverflow)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446726/running-pbc-in-windows-visual-studio. Look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pbc-devel/GRBsgXkyPTw. Do you see any answers? I certainly don't...